# how we display the record of specific patient through mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have three relational tables. i want to show all records against code from patient_Record table. i want display record by patient_record code and by patient name and by date_time

here patient_record table[table1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Xiz.png

here patient_checkup table[table2]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM6Q8.png

here patient_medicine table[table 3]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3POb.png

Comment: Join the tables, and use `WHERE table1.patient_code = 32`.

Comment: please write the proper query. i am beginner

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.code=table2.checkup_code 
where table1.code = 32;
```

Comment: i guess this won't work because both tables have column `code`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to join your tables over `code -> checkup_code` and then display all rows with `patient_code = 32`. Then your query needs to look like this:

```
SELECT    `table1`.`code`,
          `table1`.`date_time`,
          `table1`.`patient_code`,
          `table2`.`code`,
          `table2`.`checkup_code`,
          `table2`.`medicine`,
          `table2`.`potency`

FROM      `table1`

LEFT JOIN `table2.`
ON        `table2.`.`checkup_code` = `table1`.`code`

WHERE     `table1`.`patient_code` = '32'
```

Note that `SELECT *` won't work because both your tables have a column `code`.
For more information look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/left-join-optimization.html)